# IE11 : Error parsing handshake response: TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'

Tags: safari, internet-explorer-11, angular6, indexof, polyfills

Application is in Angluar CLI and i am using Signalr Connection. But in IE-11 and Safari below error displays while try to connect 'WebSockets' handshake connection response parse.

also tried to add prototype method in polyfills but that didn't worked for me.

It works fine in all other browsers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue in IE11, using @aspnet/signalr version 1.1.0.

I noticed that you are using Message Pack for the hub protocol. If you disable this and use the default JSON protocol, it should start working again and you won't receive the error "Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'" (at least for IE11, I can't speak to Safari).